# How to loop through JSON data using python?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to for loop through a json data and only look at "deadline_time" key. But I don't seem to know how to do that!

Here's my code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/") as response:
    source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

for item in data['events']['deadline_time']:
    print(item)
```

Here's what the API looks like:

```
    {
      "events": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Gameweek 1",
  ------> "deadline_time": "2021-08-13T17:30:00Z",
          "average_entry_score": 69,
          "finished": true,
          "data_checked": true,
          "highest_scoring_entry": 5059647,
          "deadline_time_epoch": 1628875800,
          "deadline_time_game_offset": 0,
          "highest_score": 150,
          "is_previous": true,
          "is_current": false,
          "is_next": false,
          ...
```

But I end up getting this error:

```
  File "API2.py", line 11, in <module>
    for item in data['events']['deadline_time']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the events not the individual deadline time.

Replace

```
for item in data['events']['deadline_time']:
    print(item)
```

With

```
for item in data['events']:
        print(item['deadline_time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`data['events']['deadline_time']` gives you the value of `deadline_time` and it's string

Replace it like this:

```
for item in data['events']:
    print(item['deadline_time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to achieve this

```
for item in data['events']:
  print(item["deadline_time"])
```